# Code works from localhost but not on server - https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050 - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stock, pythonanywhere

I am trying to access https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050. It is working fine from my localhost (code compiled in vscode) but when I deploy it on the server I get HTTP 499 error.
Did anybody get through this and was able to fetch the data using this approach?
Looks like nse is blocking the request somehow. But then how is it working from a localhost?

P.S. - I am a paid user of pythonAnywhere (Hacker) subscription

```
import requests
import time

def marketDatafn(query):
    headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'}

    main_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(main_url, headers=headers)
    
    cookies = response.cookies
    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%2050"
    nifty50DataReq = session.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=15)

    nifty50DataJson = nifty100DataReq.json()

    return nifty50DataJson['data']
```

Comment: I believe I answered your problem clearly? You can mark answer as accepted it that solved your problem and if any queries ask in comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually "Pythonanywhere" only supports those website which are in this [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).

And I have found that there are only two subdomain available under "nseindia.com", which is not that you are trying to request.

> bricsonline.nseindia.com
> bricsonlinereguat.nseindia.com

So, pythonanywhere is blocking you to sent request to that website.

Here's the [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RequestingWhitelistAdditions/) to read more about how to request to add your website there.

Comment: I am a paid user and I am able to access the other links easily.. for example bhavcopy download etc.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that in question so I believe that's your issue, which is for most of the people!

Comment: Also for that matter if we try to execute the same code in any python compiler online. it is giving an error. Not sure how it can be solved.

Comment: Your are getting 499 https status? @UBhargava

Comment: Edited the question that I am a paid user in pythonAnywhere. Yes either 499 or no response at all. It just remains in the pending state

Comment: Have you tested the same code for other sites? What's the status? Is it working perfectly fine for other websites? @UBhargava

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'tried with other websites'?? Do you mean If I ran the same code in other online compilers? yes I did but it gives me connection reset error or failed to establish the connection. However if I run it from visual studio code it runs perfectly fine. The other version of the code that runs fine on my local system is in below comments

Comment: import requests


def marketDatafn(query):    
  agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'}
  resp1 = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market',headers=agent)

  cookies=resp1.cookies
  
  nifty100DataReq = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index={}".format(query),headers=agent, cookies=cookies)

  nifty100DataJson = nifty100DataReq.json()
  return nifty100DataJson['data']
marketDatafn('NIFTY%2050')

Comment: No, I don't mean with other compiler I mean other website like as (google.com,...)

Comment: I am not sure how does it help here but I just did and it is perfectly fine. <Response [200]>

Comment: I don't get the exact answer for your problem, but "499" means something like timeout and I believe that website har set timeout it is working fine in browser, here locally. So, I believe you should try to connect to pythonanywhere staff and I think they will solve your issue probably. :)